# Get last line of HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the last line of HTML text with Javascript?

For example, a HTML request returns this response:

```
<span>blah blah blah
ha ha ha ha
tatatatata
```

How would I get the last line "tatatatata"?

Comment: Sorry, the post did not include my line breaks, but there should be one between the blahs, ha's an ta's

Comment: I edited your post to add the formatting.

Answer (score 12):

```
var html = document.getElementById('some_element').innerHTML.split(/\r?\n/);
alert(html[html.length - 1]);
```

Split by `/\r?\n/` to break the HTML into lines, then grab the last element of the array.

Note: since this is HTML, you may want to split by `/<br(?: \/)?>/` or `/<br>/`, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#your_span').html().split(/\r?\n/).pop()
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in all the HTML markup, do a split() on line breaks, and get the last item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's [`lastIndexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastIndexOf.asp), like this:

```
var your_html = 'blah<br />ha ha<br />tata';
var newline_mark = '<br />';
var last_br_position = your_html.lastIndexOf(newline_mark);
var last_line;
if (last_br_position == -1)
    last_line = your_html;
else
    last_line = your_html.substr(last_br_position + newline_mark.length);
```

Comment: this assumes your lines are split by `<br />`. if not, just change the `newline_mark` variable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one `<span>` on the page....

```
var lines = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText.split("\n");
alert(lines[lines.length-1]);
```